What is the condition to make matrix power times a vector divergent?
Let's say we have a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
I wonder what is the sufficient and necessary condition for the divergence of $$A^k v,k\rightarrow +\infty $$($\lim_{k \to \infty} A^kv=\infty$), I think one of  the situation is when $\rho(A)>1$, what about $\rho(A)=1$?
Are there any restrictions on $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ or $A$？
